# How to wait for findit result?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

Hi I am using the library [findit](https://github.com/substack/node-findit) to recursively search a directory tree for a file. I am able to find the file, but how do I wait for the search to be done before trying to do something with the file? Right now I have:

```
var path = require('path');
var finder = require('findit')(project_root_dir);
finder.on('file', function (file, stat) {
        if (path.basename(file) == 'file_im_looking_for.json') {
          stop()  // found it
          console.log('FOUND IT');
          console.log(file);
          console.log(path.basename(file));
          found_file = file;
        }
      });
// Now I want to do some stuff with found_file
```

my Issue is that it takes some time for findit to run, and so my code that references found_file later on is usually dealing with an undefined value instead of the filepath string I desire. How can I wait for the finder.on() method to finish before using my found_file variable?

Comment: Put the code which processes the file in a function and call it `process_file(file)` You don't even need the `found_file` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promise is what you need. Try this code:

```js
(async () => {
  var search = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     var finder = require('findit')(project_root_dir);
     finder.on('file', function (file, stat) {
        if (path.basename(file) == 'file_im_looking_for.json') {
          stop()  // found it
          console.log('FOUND IT');
          console.log(file);
          console.log(path.basename(file));
          resolve(file)
        }
      });
     finder.on('error', reject);
  });
  var found_file = await search;
  // do some stuff with found_file
})()
```

Answer (score -1):

It can be simply:

```
finder.on('end', function () { do_your_things; })
```